# ~でも〜ましょう and ~ましょう?

Tags: words

散歩でもしましょうか? 
散歩しましょうか?
Do they have the same meaning? I just can't totally get what ~でも〜ましょう means.

Answer (score 0):

散歩でもしましょうか? is an invitation to go for a walk or to do something else.

散歩しましょうか? is merely a question about whether to go on a walk.